# Fetching webpage using Java Socket

Tags: java, sockets, websocket, client

I am doing a homework for my class, it says that I write a program that get/retrieve a single file from web server using http, given the hostname and the name of the file on the server (For example, `https://www.facebook.com` is the hostname and '/userprofile' it would retrieve/get that user profile page). My program is written for simple website only, but the program doesn't print the raw HTML output to the console. For example, with this website `https://gustavus.edu/mcs/max/`it should print the HTML output but instead it just prints out the response info like this

```
/mcs/max
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 26 Nov 2019 01:49:48 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 162
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://gustavus.edu/mcs/max
```

I don't know if my program achieves what required in the question, and would really appreciate any help.

```
import java.io.
import java.net.*

public class client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (args.length < 1) return;

        URL url;

        try {
            url = new URL(args[0]);
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        String hostname = url.getHost();
        int port = 80;

        try (Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, port)) {

            OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output, true);

            //send HEAD request to the server use HTTP protocol
            writer.println("HEAD " + url.getPath() + " HTTP/1.1");
            writer.println("Host: " + hostname);
            writer.println("User-Agent: Simple Http Client");
            writer.println("Accept: text/html");
            writer.println("Accept-Language: en-US");
            writer.println("GET " + url.getPath() + "HTTP/1.1");
            writer.println();
            writer.flush();


            InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
            System.out.println(url.getPath());

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            //close connection
            output.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {

            System.out.println("Server not found: " + ex.getMessage());

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            System.out.println("I/O error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: HINT: https is encrypted, and on port 443. You are accessing port 80 (which is unencrypted http).

Comment: Thank you, but I changed the port to 443 and now I get a 400 bad request in the console...

Comment: Why do you have `HEAD` in `writer.println("HEAD " + url.getPath() + " HTTP/1.1");`? Pretty sure the first line should be `writer.println("GET " + url.getPath() + " HTTP/1.1");` (and remove the `HEAD`).

Comment: I just want to specify the request

Comment: If you want the HTML the request must be GET, not HEAD. When you get this response code there is no HTML. Your program is working correctly so far. If you're required to follow the redirection you need to do that, but it's hard to believe. Try a different resource and/or a different server. NB The line terminator in HTTP is specified as `\r\n`, not as whatever `println()` produces on your system.